# Testing a class without using another class

Tags: java

I'm working on a homework assignment and I'm confused about what the instructor wants. Unfortunately, when I asked for clarification it created more questions, so I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple here and I'm overthinking the issue. Here is the assignment:

> Create a class named Purchase.  Each Purchase contains an invoice
> number, amount of sale, and amount of sales tax.  Include set methods
> for the invoice number and sale amount.  Within the set() method for
> the sale amount, calculate the sales tax as 7.5% (using a static field
> in the Purchase class) of the sale amount.  Also include a display
> method that displays a purchase's details in a well formatted output
> display.
>
> Save the file as Purchase.java. Compile and run the program
> until it works and the output looks nice, add the necessary
> documentation as described in Course Documents, and then attach your
> .java file to this assignment. Do not attach the .class file, attach
> only your source code. This assignment is due the last day of the
> academic week.

I created the Purchase class with all of the required set methods and display methods, but in the past when we've been required to create a class like this we've also been required to create and provide a test class. When I asked if we needed to submit our test class, the instructor said, "you do not need a separate class, however you still must include test code."

My question is it seems like the assignment was specifically asking for a unique class for creating Purchase objects, not an application. How can I provide test code without another class? I've asked for clarification, but I'm not sure if he'll get back to me before it's due.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I absolutely necessary you can have some "test code" in a simple `main` method of the `Purchase` class:

```
public class Purchase {
  // ... your real code is here ...

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Purchase p = new Purchase();
    p.doSomeThings();
    if (p.getSomeInfo() != 42) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Oh noes! This went wrong!");
    }
    System.out.println("All Tests ok!");
  }
}
```

That's not really a clean solution and I wouldn't do that for any real production code, but if the goal is just to demonstrate that your class does what it's meant to do for a university course (and you've been explicitly told that you don't need a separate test class) then it might just be good enough.

Obviously a real test class using a proper unit testing framework (such as JUnit or TestNG) would be better.

Comment: OK thanks for this explanation. Something like this was what I was thinking, but I hadn't considered trying to put a main method in the class for testing purposes because we've never done it that way. It makes sense but I agree, it seems like something you'd never do for a real program.